# How to get the array from PHP to JAVASCRIPT through AJAX and JSON?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, wordpress

Can someone help me out? It seems like I get a string instead of an array.
Once I pass the array, which is the result of a sql query, from PHP to Javascript through AJAX, I would like to loop the array and populate some fields in a form. 
I post the code:

JAVASCRIPT

```
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#input_12_153').change(function (){
            if ($('#input_12_153').attr("value")== 'no-selection'){
                $('#input_12_48').val( '' );}
            else{
                var valor = $('#input_12_153').attr("value");
                jQuery.ajax({ // We use jQuery instead $ sign, because Wordpress convention.
                    url : '/optcat/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', // This addres will redirect the query to the functions.php file, where we coded the function that we need.
                    type : 'POST',
                    data : {
                        action : 'my_action', 
                        fieldvalue : valor,
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        alert( data );
                        //Here I would like to loop the array and get the values
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

PHP (Functions.php)

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action' ); // This lines it's because we are using AJAX on the FrontEnd.

function my_action(){
    global $wpdb;

    $tablename = $wpdb->prefix . 'rg_lead_detail';
    $lead_id = $_POST['fieldvalue'];  // This variable will get the POST 'fieldvalue'
    $form_id = 21;

    $sql = "SELECT value FROM $tablename WHERE lead_id = %d AND form_id= %d";

    $results = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( $sql, $lead_id, $form_id ), ARRAY_A );

    echo json_encode($results,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
}
```

Comment: add in php correct `header` - `header('Content-Type: application/json');` or specify  data type returned in ajax -`dataType: 'json',`

Comment: add in js `dataType: "json",`

Comment: I agree with @guradio . since you send the data from PHP to Javascript as json encoded data, adding `dataType: "json"` in your ajax will automatically parse the data into an object.

Comment: `json_encode`  returns a JSON encoded string, you need to convert that string into array using `JSON.parse()`, the `dataType` doesn't make much difference.

Answer (score 0):

Use [JSON.parse()](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp) to turn the string from PHP into an array.

```
success: function(data) {
    var results = JSON.parse(data); // like this
    alert( data );
    //Here I would like to loop the array and get the values
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I get: 

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.complete (csu.js?ver=170505-82345:77)
    at i (jquery.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith (jquery.js:2)
    at y (jquery.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.c (jquery.js:4)

Comment: where do you call `my_action()`?

Comment: my_action is a function in the file functions.php of wordpress. I call my_action when a dropdown field is selected to pass a var to the function that makes a sql query and send the array with the results back to the javascript

Comment: console.log `data` to see if it's not empty.

Comment: If I put dataType:'json', I need to change the action to complete from success otherwise it won't do anything..
If I remove dataType:'json', even if the action is success it works. The array is not empty.
I don t undestand this behaviour..

Here the values i can see in the console:

"[{"value":"ASSL u33"},{"value":"Padova"},{"value":"Pagetta"},{"value":"info@pagetta4500.it"},{"value":"Sruffo"},{"value":"sruffo@opt-ita.com"}]0"

Comment: Little update I put die() in my_action function now I get it work even if the action is success and get the array but I have the same error:

JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1
csu.js?ver=170505-84854:77 Array(6)
(index):1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.success (csu.js?ver=170505-84854:78)
    at i (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at y (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.c (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:4)

Comment: @εtiena with the `0` at the end?

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was no need to use `JSON.parse(data);` again otherwise I used to get an error of "Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1 at "
By only putting `dataType: "json"` is enough.
I post my final code:

functions.php

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action' ); // This lines it's because we are using AJAX on the FrontEnd.

function my_action(){
    global $wpdb;

    $tablename = $wpdb->prefix . 'rg_lead_detail';
    $lead_id = $_POST['fieldvalue'];  // This variable will get the POST 'fieldvalue'
    $form_id = 21;

    $sql = "SELECT value FROM $tablename WHERE lead_id = %d AND form_id= %d";

    $results = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( $sql, $lead_id, $form_id ), ARRAY_A );

    echo json_encode($results);

    die();
}
```

Javascript

```
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#input_12_153').change(function (){
            if ($('#input_12_153').attr("value")== 'no-selection'){
                $('#input_12_48').val( '' );}
            else{
                var valor = $('#input_12_153').attr("value");
                jQuery.ajax({ // We use jQuery instead $ sign, because Wordpress convention.
                    url : '/optcat/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', // This addres will redirect the query to the functions.php file, where we coded the function that we need.
                    type : 'POST',
                    data : {
                        action : 'my_action', 
                        fieldvalue : valor,
                    },
                    dataType:'json',
                    success: function(data) {
                        //var results = JSON.parse(data); // like this
                        $(data).each(function(i,val){
                            $.each(val,function(k,v){
                                alert(k+" : "+ v);     
                            });
                        });
                    }
                });
           }
       });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Yes this solution works perfectly! Thanks a lot for your support :)